# Cannot remove dynamic content (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

I cannot see why i can't remove some dynamic content with Jquery.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="formCopy">
    <!--FORM-->
    <form class="form form-inline well well-sm" id="copyForm">
        <!--SELECT objNr-->
        <select id="selectObjNr" style="width: 150px;">
            <option></option>
```

**This is my JS:**

```
//ObjNr on CHANGE
$(document).on('change', '#objNr', function(){
    //Remove old element
    $('.elNr').remove();

    //Grab selected objNR
    objNr = $(this).val();

    //Get elements for object
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: {objNr: objNr},
        success: function(result){
            //INSERT new element to DOM
            $(result).insertAfter('#objNr);

            //ENABLE SELECT2
            $( "#elNr").select2({
            });
        }
    })
})
```

**I've also tried:**

```
$('#objNr').on('change', function(){
    $(document).find('#elNr').remove();
    $(this).siblings('.elNr').remove();
```

So, i made a jsfiddle to make some tests..
Problem is that the fiddle works correct..
https://jsfiddle.net/86Lrdakc/

If i `console.log($('#elNr'))` i can see the dynamic element.

What am i missing?
The only difference is how i create the dynamic element.

**PHP**

```
//SELECT2
echo '<select id="elNr" class="elNr" style="width: 150px;">';
    //OPTIONS
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo '<option value="'.$row['element_nr'].'">'.$row['element_nr'].'</option>';
    }
//END SELECT2
echo '</select>';
```

**UPDATE**

```
//Find old dynamic element
$('#objNr').on('change', function(){
    old = $(this).siblings('#elNr'); console.log(old)
```

Console: [select#elNr.elNr, prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: select#objNr]

Dynamic content:

```
<select id="elNr" class="elNr" style="width: 150px;"><option value="001">001</option><option value="003">003</option><option value="004">004</option><option value="005">005</option><option value="006">006</option><option value="007">007</option><option value="008">008</option><option value="009">009</option><option value="010">010</option><option value="011">011</option><option value="012">012</option><option value="013">013</option><option value="014">014</option><option value="015">015</option><option value="016">016</option><option value="017">017</option><option value="018">018</option></select>
```

It seems like plugin "SELECT2" converts my select into a span?!

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" style="width: 150px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="select2-selectElNr-results" aria-labelledby="select2-selectElNr-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-selectElNr-container" title="001">001</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
```

**SOLUTION**

```
$('#objNr').on('change', function(){
    //Find old dynamic element
    oldEl = $(this).siblings('#elNr');
    if(oldEl.length){
        //Remove old SELECT2 elNr
        $(".elNr").select2('destroy');
        $(".elNr").remove();
    }
```

Comment: could you please share, output of dynamic elements?

Comment: Check what HTML markup `select2` plugin generates once initialized. I guess you would get your answer. You don't remove the element you are expecting

Comment: @vural Check update!

Comment: @A.Wolff I guess you are correct. Removing the plugins SELECT2 solved my problem. How can i do this markup check? Console element after init?!

Comment: @Mjukis Just right click on element and inspect it. It will show you generated HTML markup. Now i suppose it would work: `$(".elNr").select2('destroy').remove();`

Comment: @A.Wolff  That is just so odd. I've used this "remove" function just like this before. But when i inspect the element it seems like plugin "Select2" is making a "span" of my select...

Comment: Ya, i edited previous comment, test using `$(".elNr").select2('destroy').remove();` instead of just `$(".elNr").remove();`. Destroying plugin would remove all extra HTML markup, i guess  EDIT: works as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/0Lbgedhm/

Comment: @A.Wolff ok, problem solved! But i had to separate "destroy" & "remove" console gave me error if remove after destroy. Thank you.

Comment: @A.Wolff please state your answer. You can see my solution in my edit.

Comment: `But i had to separate "destroy" & "remove"` They probably change plugin code which no more returns original jq set. Feel free to post your solution as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Jquery plugin SELECT2.
I had to destroy it first, and then remove the select.

```
$('#objNr').on('change', function(){
    //Find old dynamic element
    oldEl = $(this).siblings('#elNr');
    if(oldEl.length){
        //Remove old SELECT2 elNr
        $(".elNr").select2('destroy');
        $(".elNr").remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without more code but maybe you've put your JS at the top of the page ? If this is the case, the element does not exist when the event is set.

You can set your event on the body to make sure dynamic elements are taken into account.

```
$('body').on('change', '#ObjNr', function() {...});
```